# Show/Hide Gridview controls when clicks on checkbox - Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

My first column of gridview contains a tetxbox and label. Second column contains check boxes. When user click on "check_all" check box the textbox of all rows should appear. Initially it is set as invisible. Also label should disappear.
And when user clicks on individual checkboxes of each row, corresponding textbox should appear and label should disappear. How can I achieve this using javascript?

```
<asp:TemplateField  
         HeaderText="Add Note" 
         itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center"  >
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("notes") %>'>
          </asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
                       runat="server" 
                       Width="100px" 
                       Text='<%# Eval("notes") %>' 
                       Visible="false">
           </asp:TextBox> 
     </ItemTemplate>
           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                        Width="60px"/>
            <ItemStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center"  
                        Width="60px">
            </ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="check_all"  
                             onclick="ShowHideChkBx(this)"  
                             runat="server" 
                             EnableViewState="true" 
                             CssClass="gridcheckbox"  />
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"
                                onclick="ShowHideChkBx(this)"
                                runat="server" Checked="false"  />
           </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript code :

```
      function ShowHideChkBx(ele) {

        var GridView = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>')
        var checkBoxes = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 1; i < GridView.rows.length; i++) {

        }
        if (ele.checked) { //to check all checkboxes when user clicks on check_all
            for (var i = 1; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
                }
                if (checkBoxes[i].type == "text") {
                    checkBoxes[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    checkBoxes[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: The aspnet `Visible=false` property is not the same as front-end css like `style=display:none`. When the visibility is set to false the TextBox does not exist on the front-end/

Comment: Initially I dont need to show tetxbox in front end. Need to make it visible through js when user clicks on checkbox

Comment: That is exactly my point. You cannot do that with js if the visibility is set to false. Use `<asp:TextBox style="display:none" Visible="true"`. Then you can display it with js.

Comment: oh ok. I will. How can i get control on textblock and label on javascript when user clcik on checkboxes?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

It can be written better, but basically your Javascript would look like:

```
// Add a shim for browsers not supporting .closest()
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest =
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i,
            el = this;
        do {
            i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
        } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement));
        return el;
    };
}

function onCheckboxClick(el) {
    var row = el.closest('tr'); // current row
    var textbox = row.querySelector("#TextBox1"); // textbox in the same row
    var label = row.querySelector("#Label1"); // label in the same row

    // if current checkbox is checked show textbox and hide label
    if (el.checked) {
      textbox.style.visibility = "visible";
      label.style.visibility = "hidden";
    // if current checkbox is unchecked hide textbox and show label
    } else {
      textbox.style.visibility = "hidden";
      label.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Just remember to change the handler on the checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"  onclick="onCheckboxClick(this)"  runat="server" Checked="false"  />
```

Comment: I have tried this, But  textbox.style.visibility = "visible";
      label.style.visibility = "hidden";  is not working. I have many other columns in gridview. is that may be the reason ?

Comment: `onCheckboxClick ` runs only on the same row of the clicked checkbox. Actually you can show/hide any HTML element, see http://jsfiddle.net/ifthenelse/93maogcp/8/

Comment: var textbox = row.querySelector("input[type='textbox']");  can I pass textbox id (here it is TextBox1)  to this? I have multiple textboxes on same row. so need to specify the textbox id

Comment: Yes, you can use any css selector, it returns the first occurrence.

Comment: If you need all the occurrences, use el.querySelectorAll()

Comment: sorry , didn't get . I want to show/hide  only this TextBox1 and Label1. There are many other columns on same row.

Comment: textbox.style.visibility = "visible";
      label.style.visibility = "hidden"; is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179831/discussion-between-ifthenelse-and-user2431727).